# When installing airflow, no files are created in the airflow_home folder

Tags: airflow

I have successfully installed it in centos7 in VMware before.
However, in the same way, there was a problem installing manually from centos7 in docker.
(The official build of CentOS.)

```
(venv) [jykim@0f0090962efa dev]$ cat /etc/*release*
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

When airflow was installed with the command below, no files were created in the specified AIRFLOW_HOME directory.

```
pip3.8 install 'apache-airflow[postgres]'
```

Naturally, we registered AIRFLOW_HOME with .bashrc and confirmed it was working fine.

```
(venv) [jykim@0f0090962efa ~]$ pwd
/home/jykim
(venv) [jykim@0f0090962efa ~]$ cd $AIRFLOW_HOME/
(venv) [jykim@0f0090962efa airflow_home]$ pwd
/home/jykim/dev/airflow/airflow_home
```

Reinstalling python resulted in the same result.

This blew the day away. I need your help!

```
(venv) [jykim@0f0090962efa airflow_home]$ python -V
Python 3.8.8
(venv) [jykim@0f0090962efa airflow_home]$ pip show apache-airflow
Name: apache-airflow
Version: 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the Airflow package will not create configuration files in the Airflow home directory. [Run Airflow once for it to create the default configuration files](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html#setting-configuration-options), e.g. with:

```
airflow info
```

Comment: hahaha i forgot it very dumb. appreciate!!